# How to run multiple operating systems on a single computer?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Dual Booting Linux and Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/30725/dual-booting-linux-and-windows-xp)
>   [Booting Multiple Operating Systems](https://superuser.com/questions/93257/booting-multiple-operating-systems)

I have a machine with Windows on it, and I would like to be able to reboot to Linux.  I am certain this is possible. How can I achieve this?

Comment: does one of these answer your question?  http://superuser.com/questions/30725/dual-booting-linux-and-windows-xp .. http://superuser.com/questions/93257/booting-multiple-operating-systems .. there are also many similar questions under the *[dual-boot]* and *[multi-boot]* tags: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot & http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-boot

Answer (score 2):

Which Operating System do you want to run?

You'll need to partition your hard disk for other OS. For details on how to do this, you can check out [this guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306559).

I would advise trying out Linux, especially [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/). Thus, let's assume that the OS you want is Ubuntu.

Two easy ways: the first method is to use Wubi Installer. Try this [guide](http://wubi-installer.org/faq.php).

[image]

Alternatively, you can try with a [Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/GetUbuntu/download). You'll need to follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD).

You can try multiple Operating Systems in [Virtual Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) such as [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) (free), [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) Workstation and [Microsoft Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/).

There is corresponding documentation on their websites.

Comment: Sweet, thanks!  Yes I want to install Ubuntu on my Windows machine, and I think the partition idea is good.  Doing a partition will make sure that files cannot be accessed between the two, correct?  Say I wanted to share files between the two, would that even be possible?  Thanks again!

Comment: That Wubi web site is having some serious problems

Comment: if you can't get wubi from its official webiste, you can try other mirrors (http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download-wubi, http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot-Manager-Disk/Wubi.shtml )

Comment: Sharing files will be possible if you use the right file system. Windows ignores partitions with linux-specific file system (like ext3/ext4/reiserfs) but linux is able to read and write nearly everything (meanwhile even ntfs). So you would just have to create a fat32 or ntfs partition in order to access it from windows and linux.

Comment: I don't think I can try Wubi on Windows 7 :(

Comment: @Josh Stodola Why ?

Comment: @mgpyone It does not support it!

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy. Moden Linux distributions generally install a bootmanager, i.e. a piece of software that shows up on startup and lets you choose which operating system to boot.

It looks like this:

[image: grub bootmanager]

To get this, you simply download a Linux-distribution of your choice and install it according to the instructions. Along with the install a bootmanager will be installed and you are free to select the desired operating system on reboot.